# Help me fine what kind of Transformer this is

Tags: transformer

Can you help me find what kind of transformer this is? I'm having a hard time looking it up based on the numbers. It came off a Kenmore 220V stove

[image: Side View]

[image: Front View]

Comment: This is a transformer from a switching-mode power supply. These are specially made for this one supply you have it from. If you had another supply of exactly the same type, and another part broken, you could made one out of two. If not, it means *throw away*.

Comment: Is there a way to determine specs and find a replacement?

Comment: has the smoke come from the transformer or another component near it?

Comment: both, Someone hooked it up to 3 phase power to it. They blew the thermal fuse inside the transformer and all the enamel in the coil looks cooked.

Comment: A yellow one it seems

Comment: You could call GCi technologies and ask them which scrap metal dump they sent their obsolete spare parts to, grab a shovel and see what you could find there.

Comment: Your best bet on this is to go to one of those appliance parts websites, look up the model of your stove, usually they will have a diagram of replaceable parts, availability, cost, etc.